# Eclipse CDT global settings (for multiple projects)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to use Eclipse CDT for C++ developement. I'm working in a small team. Our project consists of multiple shared libraries and executables. I know I have to create one project per library/executable. But there are things that are common to multiple projects (like include directories, directory for binaries etc...). I would also like to share these settings with team. What is the best way to accomplish this?